# J2ME Amazon upload by REST API not working by POST object

Tags: amazon-s3, java-me

I'm trying to upload a file using J2ME code to Amazon S3 through the Amazon REST API(POST object). This is my code:

```
String url = "http://xxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com";
       //open connection
       hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
       //set Post data
       hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
       //set postvalues
       hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----1234567890");
       hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
       hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
       //hc.setRequestProperty("acl", "public-read");
       //hc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
       hc.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "300");
       hc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
       hc.setRequestProperty("AWSAccessKeyId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
       hc.setRequestProperty("key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
       //hc.setRequestProperty("file", "contactss.vcf");
       //hc.setRequestProperty("submit", "asdasdasdasd");
       hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", data.length() + ("-----1234567890".getBytes().length * 2) + "");
       hc.setRequestProperty("Content-length", data.length() + ("-----1234567890".getBytes().length * 2) + "");

       DataOutputStream dos = hc.openDataOutputStream();
       //dos.write("-----1234567890".getBytes());
       dos.write(data.getBytes());
```

After executing it. I'm getting this below response:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><RequestId>686AB7E3C10779B9</RequestId><HostId>75OKRHQ59yfJLZ8nThsNE8G7PukbBdnoL7lonZX6EprPpqik5pAcKOK/TG9tGBdA</HostId></Error>
```

But the file is not uploaded to Amazon S3. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file line is commented out, your are not even sending a file.

```
...
hc.setRequestProperty("key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
//hc.setRequestProperty("file", "contactss.vcf");
//hc.setRequestProperty("submit", "asdasdasdasd");
hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", data.length() + ("------1234567890".getBytes().length * 2) + "");
...
```

Having said that I strongly suggest you used the AWS Java SDK:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/